# Sql statement returning incorrect data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ms-access

I am confused as to why my SQL select statement is returning incorrect data. In my database the value is `009698` and it is returning `9698`. Could someone shed some light as to why this would be happening.

It is an MS Access 2010 database and the column is `text` and the size is 6.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try
        DBConnection.connect()

        sql = "SELECT MAX([Request no]) from Requests WHERE Customer = '" & cmbCustomer.Text & "' "
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim id As Integer

        cmd.CommandText = sql
        cmd.Connection = oledbCnn
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read()
                id = CInt(dr.Item(0))
                id = (id) + 1
        End While

        'MessageBox.Show("00" & id)
        'sql = "INSERT INTO Requests ([Request no], Customer) VALUES ('" & id & "', '" & cmbCustomer.Text & "')"

        cmd.Dispose()
        'dr.Close()
        oledbCnn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are treating the returned value as integer so '009698' and '9698' are the same values in this context.

If you want to later convert it to a six-digit string, you can do:

```
Dim stringId as String
While dr.Read()
    id = CInt(dr.Item(0))
    id = (id) + 1
    stringId = id.ToString().PadLeft(6, "0"c)
End While
```

Comment: How do I amend please Szymon

Comment: What I want to do is get the actual value of '009698' and not 9698. BTW Your code produces 'expression expected' at 6,. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I gave you C# syntax, instead of VB.NET. Use this: `id.ToString().PadLeft(6, "0"c)`

Comment: That errors with: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since the field is text, why not use the `GetString` function on the `DataReader`.

```
Dim id As String

While dr.Read
  ''The string value returned from the database
  Dim stringID = dr.GetString(0)

  ''convert the string to an int and add 1
  Dim numericID = CInt(stringID) + 1

  ''convert the number back to a string with leading 0
  id = numericID.ToString.PadLeft(stringID.Length, "0")

End While
```

I'm assuming you're trying to get the string value from a db, convert it to a number, add one, and then convert it back to the string format with leading zeros.

Comment: The field is a 'text' field and I do not wish to convert it to int just keep as a string. Thanks